# Cannot browse Zend Framework project "Class 'Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter' not found "

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend, and i'm trying to create my first zend application. I'm following the tutorial here. http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/
Unfortunately, i'm using xampp. I found that it arises some conflictions when using xampp with zend. 
i have added

> C:\xampp\php

to my system variables and I edited include_path in php.ini file to

> .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library

But when i'm trying to view my newly created project, it outputs this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf-tutorial\library\Zend\Filter\Inflector.php on line 19

I have no idea since i'm new to Zend. Please help me out guys...

Comment: Coould you post the index.php in your public dir ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question because I was having the very same problem, hopefully it will be useful in the future, sorry for resurrecting a fairly dead post.

For me, this problem was because I downloaded zend framework 2, and added that Library to my include path in PHP. However it turned out that my OS (A linux distro called crunchbang) comes with zend framework 1.1 pre-installed.

My autoloader was loading basically everything from the 1.1 library, and when it didn't find it, it fell back to the 2.2 library, it found the Inflector in 2.2 but for whatever reason, didn't find the AbstractFilter that was right next to it.

I figured this out by adding a register_shutdown_function that blurted out all the included files, using get_included_files().

Once I had figured out the problem, it was an easy enough fix, I removed the zend framework 2.2 include from my PHP config, and presto, everything was golden :)

Regards,
Phil,

Comment: the problem is not the conflict, the problem is with the version of ZF, removing ZF1 did not do any good, What solved the issue for you was downgrading to ZF1. the problem still exists if you remove Zf1 and stay with ZF2 only.